# Cookie update on second visit to page in php

Tags: php, http, cookies, setcookie

I have a case where i want to make use of the cookie to redirect to another page if the page is already visited . However i want this to be done on the " 2nd" and NOT on the first time the user visits the page . My guess is that i somehow need to incorporate Cookie with a Counter but i dont know how to do it . Here is what i have so far .

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['beenhereonce'])) {
   $redirect_url = "Location: home.php";
} else {
    setcookie("beenhereonce",time()+120);
    $redirect_url = "Location: form.php";
}
```

I want beehereonce to be set on the 2nd time when the user visits the page . how can i improve this to achieve my goal ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cookie to keep the quantity of visits and then control your code.

```
// Checking if cookie exist
if( isset($_COOKIE['visits']) )
{
    // Checking if the user already visited the site
    if( $_COOKIE['visits'] >= 1 )
        $redirect_url = "Location: home.php";

    // Increasing cookie value
    setcookie("visits", $_COOKIE['visits'] + 1, time()+120);
}
else
{
    // First visit
    $redirect_url = "Location: form.php";
    setcookie("visits", 1, time()+120);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just set the value of your cookie. this value will count the times that the page has been visited.
You can then check by doing :

```
if( isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']) )
{    
    if( $_COOKIE['cookiename[count]'] == '2' ) {
        $redirect_url = "...";
    }
    else {
        $redirect_url = "...";
        setcookie("cookiename[count]", $_COOKIE['cookiename[count]'] + 1, time()+X);
    }
}
else {
    setcookie("cookiename[count]", 1, time()+X);
}
```

X is the time after which your cookie will expire

Answer (score 0):

You could try this at the top:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['beenhereonce'])) {
   $redirect_url = "Location: home.php";
}
```

And this at the bottom:

```
setcookie("beenhereonce",time()+120);
```

That way, the cookie is set at the end of the first page load, and checked on the second page load.